# When implementing DKIM, should I publish DNS first or start signing first?

Tags: dkim

I am about to implement DKIM signing on my domain, but couldn't find information about which one to start first: publish DNS or start signing keys.

Explains better:

Considering the time DNS takes to spread out, so:

- **If I start signing first**, people will see my signed messages before they can see my DNS entry.
- **If i publish first**, people will see my DNS entry but messages won't be signed.

Which one won't result in messages being rejected?

Answer (score 5):

You should add the DKIM record in DNS first.

No one will know how to look up your DNS record before you start sending signed messages.

The query to find your key will be something like `myselector._domainkey.example.com. IN TXT`, where *myselector* is the selector as found in the DKIM signed email.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was my first idea, but I could not find any reference.